# Debian Permissions denied in docker volumes for external HD

Tags: debian, permissions, docker, external-hdd

Docker in Raspberry PI 4 with external HD (NTFS type) connected. There are some docker containers running with volumes mapped to the external HD such a:

```
  - /media/myExternalHD/docker_config/app1:/home/app1/.app1
  - /media/myExternalHD/incoming:/incoming
  - /media/myExternalHD/temp:/temp
```

My userID is 1000:1000 and is identify in enviroments variables in the compose as well:

```
  - PUID=1000
  - PGID=1000
```

When the container need to modify or write in the files located in the volumes permissions error occurred:

```
 2022-09-10 22:37:25: 22:37:25: Error: File '/temp/001.part' couldn't be renamed '/incoming/file1.txt' (error 0: Invalid argument)
 2022-09-10 22:37:25: Suspending upload of file: BFF4855E6759474EB3DCDAW3FFB5B71
 2022-09-10 22:37:00: 22:37:00: Error: Impossible to set permissions for the file '/incoming/file1.txt' (error 1: Operation not permitted)
 2022-09-10 22:37:25: 22:37:25: Error: Impossible to set permissions for the file '/temp/001.part.met.backup' (error 1: Operation not permitted)
 2022-09-10 22:37:25: 22:37:25: Error: Impossible to set permissions for the file '/temp/001.part.met.bak' (error 1: Operation not permitted)
```

Here another cointaner error:

```
     os.chmod(filename, 0o600)
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/config/settings/pyload.cfg'
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyload/core/config/parser.py", line 240, in save_config
    self.save()
    self.save_config(self.config, self.configpath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyload/core/config/parser.py", line 299, in save
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyload/core/config/parser.py", line 321, in set
```

I did change the folder ownership to my user:

```
sudo chown -R myuserid:docker /media/myExternalHD
```

and

```
sudo chown -R myuserid /media/myExternalHD
```

but didnt fix the issues, any idea?

Comment: Do you have to use NTFS or can you reformat the filesystem on the external drive to use a native-Linux filesystem (such as ext4)?

Comment: Use options when mount https://askubuntu.com/questions/113733/how-to-mount-a-ntfs-partition-in-etc-fstab

Comment: Thanks @gapsf, actually that answer solved my issues.

Comment: @roaima there is not such an option for me, i need to work with NTFS for this drive.